# Get all interfaces a sdk provides

Tags: java, interface, sdk

In our project, we provide a java sdk to other teams and there is no document.
With time going on and many developers come and go, we now even don't know how many interfaces we provide.

In this situation, is there any way to get all interfaces we provided?

Comment: Well, in theory every public class would be accessible to the users of a library so you could check which libraries are meant to contain the interfaces/api and collect all public classes, methods and fields in those libraries.

Comment: @Thomas Thanks for your reply. I check the code, and found that actually there are also some methods marked as "public" but only used by inner logic... ┑(￣Д ￣)┍

Comment: Well, public methods that are only used internally are sometimes a necessity because using other modifiers might result in quite some clutter. That's why you often find api libs that only contain what's intended to form the api for some library and the impl libs contain the inner logic which might contain "public" classes/methods as well.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at [JavaDoc](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/index-137868.html)

It can produce documentation in a nice html format, see: [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/package-summary.html)